# Ajax parameters to arcGIS's find Address

Tags: arcgis-online, jquery, ajax

I write a ajax to consume the arcGIS services to return json results, I have tried so many way for the findAddress function parameter, non seems work, plese help.  Below is my code:

```
     function AddrCandidates()
    {

        var obj = {};
            obj.Street = $.trim($("[id*=txtStreet]").val());
            obj.City = $.trim($("[id*=txtCity]").val());
            obj.State = $.trim($("[id*=txtState]").val());
            obj.Zip5 = $.trim($("[id*=txtZip5]").val());


             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                    
                url: "http://something/arcgis/rest/services/GeocodingResources/USA_CompositeAll/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates",
                data: { data: {Address: "380 New York St", City: "Redlands", State: "CA", Zip: "92373"},},
               // data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                datatyp: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var results = data.d;
                    var candidateAddr = results.candidates;       
                    alert(results);                          

                    }
                    else {
                        alert("No address found");
                    }
                },
                failure: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
                    alert('Error happens: ' + err);
                }
            });             
      }
```

The example usage address in document is:  http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Geocode_USA/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Address=380+New+York+Street&City=Redlands&State=CA&Zip=92373